# include the GUI from another process in my qt application

Tags: qt, findwindow

Would you be kind to answer these questios ?

1. Is there an alternative to FindWindow, but which is cross-platform ?
2. How can I include the GUI from another process in my qt application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: if it had been possible, it would have already been implemented by Qt team.
Please note that identifying processes in various OSes is different, so is identifying "foreign" windows.